# How to get attributes from parents of an xml node efficiently

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm working on a PHP script using SimpleXML / XPath that needs to print citations for sentences from an XML file which has structure similar to the following:

```
<text name="text_title">
  <book name="book_title">
    <chapter name="chapter_title">
      <sentence name="sentence_number" id="0000">
        <word attr="desired_val" id="1111" />
        <word attr="undesired_val" id="2222" />
      </sentence>
    </chapter>
  </book>
</text>
```

The issue is that I need to return each sentence containing a word bearing attr="desired_val", and then a citation containing its text, book, chapter, and sentence number. I'm currently doing the first part with the xpath query

```
//word[@$attr='desired_val']/ancestor::sentence
```

and the second part with a series of subsequent xpath queries based on the ID attribute of each returned sentence, e.g. for the text node:

```
/text/[book/chapter/sentence[@id={$id}]]/@name
```

(and so on, for the other relevant nodes). My issue is that this becomes grossly inefficient with large numbers of records, and is causing the script to timeout with more than about ten results. Can anyone suggest ideas about a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you share desired output? How exactly you want to simplify your expression? Do you want to get rid of `book/chapter/sentence` or what?

Comment: I guess that the number of words matches per text is quite big. This leads to redundant results of text elements. Are you really interested in a redundant result list? If not it would be sufficient to stop the search in a text element after the first word match in that text element.

Comment: `/text/[book/chapter/sentence[word[@id={$id}]]]/@name`

Comment: I should have specified that once the sentence ancestor is returned, its id value is bound to $id. I'll edit momentarily to represent that, but the second XPath query is correct for what I want it to do. @ceving is correct about the large number of matches -- unfortunately, that's the nature of the beast. I do indeed need to get all of them, not a singleton. 

Desired output is, for example, with the structure given above, something more or less like

    "1111 2222: text_title, Book book_title, Chapter chapter_title, sentence sentence_number"

Comment: It seems like it should be easier than it is, for a given node, to return, say, the value of the "name" attribute (assuming it exists) for each of the ancestors of that node, which is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all matches, the only optimization I can imagine is to reduce the enormous amount of queries. It takes much time to build the whole list of matches, in order to seek for each match into the document to collect the remaining information. Instead it would be better to query the necessary data from you document in just one step. The same problem occurs in database applications, where people execute too many SQL statements instead of doing everything in just one query.

The SQL for XML is called XQuery. If you use XQuery instead of XPath you can collect all the necessary data in just one step. The following example has been tested with [Saxon-HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) as a XQuery engine.

```
<results>
{
  for $x in doc("text.xml")/text/book/chapter/sentence/word
  where $x/@attr = "desired_val"
  return <match text="{$x/../../../../@name}"
                book="{$x/../../../@name}"
                chapter="{$x/../../@name}"
                sentence="{$x/../@name}" />
}
</results>
```

The following command

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar net.sf.saxon.Query '!indent=yes' text.xquery
```

extracts the required information from the document in just one step.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <match chapter="chapter_title"
          text="text_title"
          book="book_title"
          sentence="sentence_number"/>
</results>
```

Saxon-HE can be installed on Ubuntu by the following command.

```
apt-get install libsaxonhe-java
```

I do not know which XQuery engine is best suited for PHP.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip -- I said to a friend last night "what I need is SQL for XML", so this seems promising. I'll look into it and report any results. For PHP, these look to be the main games in town:  

[zorba](http://www.zorba.io/home),  

[BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Main_Page),  

[Xquery Lite](http://phpxmlclasses.sourceforge.net/show_doc.php?class=class_xquery_lite.html)

Comment: I was able to get everything working exactly as desired (and quite speedily) by installing and using [BaseX](http://basex.org/) in server mode. The alternative to the formerly server-murdering query returned in 338ms or so. Really appreciate the help, @ceving and everyone.